# python split string json into multiple variables and create dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, data-transform

Below is my string in python3

Please assume below string is in a loop

On First loop I get below string string as input

```
string='{a:1,b:1}{a:2,b:2}{a:3,b:4}'
```

On Second loop I get below string as input

```
string='{a:1,b:6}{a:2,b:6}'
```

On each loop pandas dataframe should created as below:

First loop

```
a b
1 1
2 2
3 4
```

second loop

```
a b
1 6
2 6
```

Can anyone help with this I am struggling to crack this logic

Comment: what you show as input strings are not valid JSON.

Comment: I wonder why there is `a 6` in the end of first loop.

Comment: I am getting data in kinesis streams @buran . SO message is getting appended at the end I should find away to split these

Comment: If you could share your dataframe which is producing these strings on iterations, would be great.

Comment: Hi Mayank, Please check below code snippet
tmp = str(my_json)
i = tmp.rfind('a') # index of last appearance a
i = i-2 #index between jsons
first_json = json.loads(tmp[2:i])
second_json = json.loads(tmp[i:-1])

This will work If I have 2 jsons. But in streaming there can be 4 json's coming at single shot . This split has to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input data by `regex`, then parse the output as `json` object

```
>>> import re
>>> string='{a:1,b:1}{a:2,b:2}{a:3,b:4}'
>>> r = '({a:\d+,b:\d+})'
>>> out = [item for item in re.split(r, string) if item !='']
>>> out
['{a:1,b:1}', '{a:2,b:2}', '{a:3,b:4}']
```

**Update**

Use this regex pattern for matching any character:

`r = '({a:.*?[^,],b:.*?[^}]})'`

Result:

```
>>> import re
>>> string='{a:1ac,b:1_e}{a:2zz,b:222}{a:33,b:44}'
>>> r = '({a:.*?[^,],b:.*?[^}]})'
>>> out = [item for item in re.split(r, string) if item !='']
>>> out
['{a:1ac,b:1_e}', '{a:2zz,b:222}', '{a:33,b:44}']
```

Comment: thank you mtdot what if I need to match any character  instead of \d+ what should I give